# My laptop cannot connect to WiFi

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, laptop

I just encountered the problem after my laptop lost power unexpectedly in a night on 2021.12.27 (yyyy/MM/dd). After I charged it and rebooted my laptop, the WiFi services were broken. All the devices in my house can connect to WiFi except my laptop. I checked the event log of my laptop, there are many duplicated events with the same ID 7024. The event log said:

```
"WinHttp Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service" service terminated due to the following service-specific errors:
Access denied.
```

I think this is why my laptop cannot connect to WiFi. For more information, please go to [the question I asked in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70892150/windbg-cannot-download-any-symbol-files).

Information about my laptop:

- Windows 10 21H1
- Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
- Realtek 8821CE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC

Comment: Probably worth adding the laptop brand and model. Like I know my wife's Lenovo Yoga 510 has a wifi issue cured by restarting networking in a cmd prompt and rebooting; I've no idea what wifi card it has in it though.

Comment: Try reinstalling / updating the wireless card driver. (a) this may fix the issue and (b) there may be a hardware issue with the wireless card because of the power out.

Comment: Also, try removing the connection to your WiFi router, reboot, and create a new connection, inputting the service name and password.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik My laptop cannot search any connection, when I click the icon in the right bottom corner, it didn't show me any available connection.

Comment: @John Can you tell me where the wireless driver is? I tried to search my wireless card model, and I went to Realtek website. Is the website I probably need?

Comment: Try either the website for the Computer manufacturer or the website for the wireless card itself. One of those two should have drivers..  You ca get a card model using Device Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have found the solution: just reset the network and reboot my laptop. After that my laptop could connect to WiFi successfully.